# Calculating probability of exceeding fixed Hash table bucket chain depth

Tags: probability

I'm attempting to create a Hash table in hardware and I would like to calculate the optimal table size and chain length (for collisions). Unlike in software, I can't easily (and don't want to) grow my table, and I'd like to set a fixed chain length per bucket. So having some probability equations would be excellent--I'm particularly interested in calculating the probability of exceeding the chain length for any bucket.

For example, say I have 4000 random values I'm inserting, my table size is 64K buckets, and each bucket has a chain length of 4 for collisions. What is the probability that I will exceed the chain length of any bucket? The number of values I will be inserting is fixed, but their contents is unknown, so I can't necessarily simulate the exact behavior.

I've done a bunch of google searching, but can't seem to find this even though it seems like an interesting problem. I've found equations to calculate the probability of a single collision, but I need to go further.

Comment: I asked a similar question a while ago (about the expected number of inserted values before overflow, rather than the probability), at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171179/throwing-balls-into-b-buckets-when-does-some-bucket-overflow-size-s -- apart from the answer below, the comments there also pointed me to [_"Balls into Bins": A Simple and Tight Analysis_ by Martin Raab and Angelika Steger](http://www14.informatik.tu-muenchen.de/personen/raab/publ/balls.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

Your problem can be cast as a variation of the Birthday Problem where the year has 64K days, there are 4000 people in the room, and we are asking if 5 or more people have the same birthday.  According to [1], if $B$ is the number of people in the room when the first $b$-way collision occurs and there are $r$ days in the year, then
$$P(B > t r^{1-1/b}) \sim \exp(-t^b / b!)$$
For your example, we have $r = 64,000$, $b = 5$, and solving $t r^{1-1/b} = 4,000$ for $t$, we find $t \approx 0.5716$, so $$P(B > 4,000) \approx 0.999492$$

1. Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick, *Analytic Combinatorics*, Note II.8.

Comment: +1. For anyone else trying to find the reference, the Note II.8 is on page 116.

Comment: Very, very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: This is useful but not exactly what the question asks for: "What is the probability that I will exceed the chain length of any bucket?" This answers "What is the probability that I will need B number of items to exceed the chain length of any bucket?"

Comment: @sudo No, the answer here transforms birthday problem and gives you probability of *not* exceeding your chaining limit (i.e. in example above probability of fatal collision is 0.05%)