# Distribution of repeated hash collisions?

Tags: probability

With $k$ samples hashed to $n$ possible values, I understand average number of collisions will be:

$$N(n,k)~= \frac{k(k-1)}{2n}$$

However what I don't understand is how to determine the probability distribution for the number of collisions per value.

Example: With $n=2^{24}$, and $k=1,000,000$, then there are average $29,802$ collisions. But what is the chance that at least one hash collides more than 64 times? Will it simply be a sample of 64 in 29,802 possible values?

Comment: I tried to improve the question format . Please check it. Also, I don't get you number $29,802$ for $n=2^{32}$ but for $n=2^{24}$

Comment: This is a well known but not easy problem.

See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614147 and http://www.dblab.ntua.gr/~gtsat/collection/scheduling/Balls%20into%20Bins%20A%20Simple%20and%20Tight%20Anal.pdf